# Stop sign hidden by tree

Tags: united-states, real-estate, traffic

Whose responsibility is it to keep the sign visible.

My understanding of "easements" is that one may own title to a parcel but easements allow others to use or have access to parts of private property.

- That parcel may include a sidewalk. It must open for use by others for walking. This sidewalk though must be maintained in good working order by the property owner.
- Said parcel may also have a tree. The utility company has an easement that permits access for such tasks as maintaining their lines should said tree be interfering in some manner.
- That parcel may also include a stop sign. That overgrown tree may also be blocking viewing of stop sign.

Does the town perform tree maintenance to keep stop sign visible, or is the property owner required to ensure his tree does not obstruct stop sign.

Feel free to correct any incorrect jargon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the law of the specific jurisdiction, but there is non-trivial similarity in those rules across the US. The general rule is that the person who owns the property must maintain the property. There are often local ordinances that explicitly say that, [for example this](https://www.codepublishing.com/WA/Shoreline/html/Shoreline12/Shoreline1205.html) which is the legal mechanism behind [this](https://www.shorelinewa.gov/services/street-maintenance/brush-tree-trimming-for-sight-distance) guidance on tree-trimming. A municipality can do the trimming, or they can send official letters to property owners telling them to trim the bushes. It does not matter whether the sign is on your property via an easement, what matters is where the tree is. You are not responsible for trimming your neighbor's tree if the stop sign is on your property.